# Position relative to a parent's parent

Tags: css, css-position

I've got a CSS menu something like this...

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="...">Menu item</li>
    <li><img src="...">Menu item2</li>
</ul>
```

My CSS currently gives me this...

[image]

What I want is something like this...

[image]

I've tried to trim down the CSS to the relevant bits - let me know if I've omitted anything crucial...

```
ul#menu li ul li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 1px #808080;
}

ul#menu li ul li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}

ul#menu li ul li img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
}
```

The problem is that the image is a child of the `<li>` which is not the full width of the `<ul>`, so the `position: relative; left: 0px;` relates to the `li` not the `ul`.

How can I position the image relative to the `ul`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since these images are not actually part of the content, remove the `img` elements from the html and add one line to your CSS:

```
ul#menu li ul li {
  background: url(/Content/images/nav/Left.png) 5px center no-repeat;
}
```

This will set the arrow as a background image that is always 5px from the left edge and automatically centered, even if the menu item spans two lines, as a couple of them do.

Comment: Thanks, you're right... It's not content and doesn't belong in the html

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution

```
ul#menu li ul li img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your 
`ul#menu li ul li` width to `100%`

```
ul#menu li ul li {
    width: 100%; //Make sure you have a set px width somewhere else in the menu hierarchy
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: solid 1px #808080;
}
```

Then set the img as `absolute`

```
ul#menu li ul li img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```